# Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution

Let `X~gamma(2,1)`.

Find:

```
P(X>=2)
(X<=10)
```

I'm struggling to determine how to solve this. I know you must integrate some function from 2 to infinity and 0 to 10 but don't know what to integrate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and Mathematics instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two ways to define Gamma-distribution - one with scaling 'theta' and another with inverse scale 'beta', see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Fortunately, for parameter value of 1 there is no difference.

So you have to integrate PDF

```
f(x) = (1/G(2)) * x * exp(-x)
```

Gamma function at 2 is equal to 1. G(2)=1, so

```
P(x) = S x exp(-x) dx
```

where `S` is integration notation.

```
P(x) = -(x+1)*exp(-x)
```

So now you have to substitute limits